# 1 in 8 chance of an event decreases by 25%, what is it?

Tags: probability

If there is a 1 in 8 chance of an event and there is a further 25% reduction in this event happening what is the answer expressed in terms of 1 in X chance?

My first calculation I worked out as 1 in 32. 
0.125 x 0.25 =0.03125

Then 1 in 12 (more guesswork) and then 3 in 32 
0.125 x 0.25 = 0.03125
0.125 - 0.03125 = 0.09375.

But now I just have no idea. Any thoughts?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Multiply $\frac{1}{8}$ by $1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a much more positive response (more help and fewer votes to close) if you show that you've made an attempt to do the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts on this?  Where is your difficulty?

Comment: Hi saulspatz - I first tried 1/8 x 1/4 which is 1/32 then I guessed it was closer to 1 in 12. Then I tried 1/8 - 1/4 and add result to 1/8 which gave me 3/32. Basically I have no idea! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability starts out as $\frac 18$.  If we reduce that by $25\%$ we multiply it by $\frac 34,$ getting a probability of $\frac 3{32}$.  If you want to express that as $1$ in something it is $1$ in $\frac {32}3=10\frac 23$.  There is no whole number answer.

Comment: Thank you Ross! That means it’s close to 1 in 11 which I can use in my case, cheers!